# How to automatically add a property on every Entities

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony5, doctrine-extensions

It's been days that I'm trying to achieve the following :

Add a `deletedAt` property on every entities **by default** without having to use a trait, or adding inheritance (or mapped superclasses) to all of my already created entities.

The goal here is to also make it work with doctrine migration script so that it would automatically add the associated column in every tables.

Tried to subscribe to the `Doctrine\ORM\Events::loadClassMetadata` event this way

```php
    class ClassMetadataEventSubscriber implements EventSubscriber
    {
        public function getSubscribedEvents()
        {
            return [
                Events::loadClassMetadata
            ];
        }
        
        public function loadClassMetadata(LoadClassMetadataEventArgs $args) {
            $metadata = $args->getClassMetadata();
            $metadata->mapField([
                'fieldName' => 'deletedAt',
                'type' => 'datetime',
                'nullable' => true,
                'columnName' => 'deleted_at'
            ]);
        }
    }
```

But I get the `ReflectionProperty::_construct()` Exception

> App\Entity\Etudiant::$deletedAt does not exist

> Exception trace:
> at /srv/api/vendor/doctrine/persistence/lib/Doctrine/Persistence/Mapping/RuntimeReflectionService.php:90
> ReflectionProperty->__construct()
> Doctrine\Persistence\Mapping\RuntimeReflectionService->getAccessibleProperty()
> Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataInfo->wakeupReflection()
> Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataFactory->wakeupReflection()
> Doctrine\Persistence\Mapping\AbstractClassMetadataFactory->loadMetadata()
> Doctrine\Persistence\Mapping\AbstractClassMetadataFactory->getMetadataFor()
> Doctrine\Persistence\Mapping\AbstractClassMetadataFactory->getAllMetadata()
> Doctrine\Migrations\Provider\OrmSchemaProvider->createSchema()
> Doctrine\Migrations\Generator\DiffGenerator->createToSchema()
> Doctrine\Migrations\Generator\DiffGenerator->generate()
> Doctrine\Migrations\Tools\Console\Command\DiffCommand->execute()

Also, the `deletedAt` property is here to enable soft deletion through [gedmo/doctrine-extensions](https://github.com/doctrine-extensions/DoctrineExtensions)

Comment: Metadata is basically just the mapping between your entity properties and the database.  It's not going to add any properties to your actual entity.  An editor might be your best bet.  I suppose if you have thousands of entities then maybe something with [rector](https://github.com/rectorphp/rector)?  And make sure you really want to do this.  Things like 'soft delete' have kind of fallen out of favor.  They can really mess things up.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, didn't know about rector actually, seems like a great tool to keep everything in place. Thanks for your warning too about 'soft delete', I'll take your advice.